# jquery click event not working after opening other links

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i've created a div class (.link_bar) which has No. of links in it. Along with it i have some div class (.slide, .slide1, .slide2) which i have used them as jquery selector.
When i load the page and click on the jquery selector,click event works fine. When i click on the link, it also works fine. But when i click on the jquery selector again its not working. In other words jquery works fine unless and until i don't click on a link.

My jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slide').click(function(){
$('.ext').slideToggle('fast');
});

$('.slide1').click(function(){
$('.cp').slideToggle('fast');
});

$('.slide2').click(function(){
$('.diff').slideToggle('fast');
});});
```

My CSS contains:

```
div.link_bar {
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 0 auto;
  height:27px;
  background: rgba(255, 217, 179, .4);
  position: relative;
  bottom: -97px;  
  }

div.link_bar a {
  color:white;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 4px 4px 6px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:none;
  }

div.link_bar .slide, .slide1 {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 4px 4px 6px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color: white;
}

div.link_bar .slide2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 4px 4px 6px; 
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DataAutomate</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>


<body>
<div class="top_bar">
<div class="foo_bar">
<div class="link_bar">
        <a href="/data/">DATA</a>
        <a href="/operators/">OPERATORS</a>
        <a href="/regions/">REGIONS</a>
        <a href="/links/">LINKS</a>
        <a href="/remov/">DELETE-ALL</a>
        <a href="/ofline/">EXTRACT-FILE</a>
        <div class="slide">EXTRACTOR</div>
        <div class="slide1">CREATE PACKS</div>
        <div class="slide2">DIFFER</div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="ext">
        <%= render :partial => "/data/do_extract.html.erb"%>
        </div>

        <div class="cp">
        <%= render :partial => "/data/create.html.erb"%>
        </div>

        <div class="diff">
        <%= render :partial => "/data/compare.html.erb"%>
        </div>


</div>      
</div>
</div>

<div id="center">

<%= yield %>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example:

When i click on "Extractor" div class (.ext) slides down and when i click "Extractor" again it slides back. -- This part working fine

When i click on "DATA" page gets redirected to the specified link. --This part is also working fine.

When i click on the "Extractor" again nothing is happening --This is the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if additional information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a turbolinks related issue whilst using

```
$(document).ready()
```

You should try binding to the turbolinks `page:load` event instead, e.g.

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () { 
  // your JS here
}
```

Edit:

Rails actually suggests using the `page:change` event instead of `page:load`,  it's worth checking out the Rails docs on turbolinks for more background / info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks

Comment: This method worked. thank you. Thank you for the link too.

Answer (score 0):

You MAY want to bind to document:

```
$(document).on('click', '.slide1', function(){
 $('.cp').slideToggle('fast');
});
```